# How query by global secondary index with DynamoDBContext

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

i have this class with this attributes:

1. ContactId -> HashKey
2. Email -> Global Seconday Index Hash Key
3. CreatedAt -> Property

Actually, i have this method, but throw me an exception because "Email" property is not a HashKey. How can i get an item using a secondary index and DynamoDBContext class? I found some examples, but all of them uses a low-level api.

```
public Contact Get(string email)
        {
            Contact entity = null;
            using (var context = new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient()))
            {
                entity = context.Load(new Contact() { Email = email });
            }
            return entity;
        }
```

EDIT: Actually, this code work for me. It assume that "email" is unique:

```
public Contact Get(string email)
        {
            Contact entity = null;
            using (var context = new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient()))
            {
                entity = context.Query<Contact>(email, new DynamoDBOperationConfig {IndexName = "Email-index"}).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            return entity;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If using .NET core or .NET 5 and higher with async API calls, the following should work. Note the **QueryAsync** method and **GetRemainingAsync().Result** which returns the result of the completed query task.

```
public Contact Get(string email)
{
    Contact entity = null;
    using (var context = new DynamoDBContext(new AmazonDynamoDBClient()))
    {
         entity = context.QueryAsync<Contact>(email, 
             new DynamoDBOperationConfig {IndexName = "Email-index"})
             .GetRemainingAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return entity;
}
```